# Find out ID of 'at' job from within it

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, at-job

When I schedule a job with 'at' it is assigned an id, viz:

job 44 at 2014-01-28 17:30

When that job runs I would like to get at that id from within it.  This is on Centos, FWIW.  I have established that no environment variable contains the ID.  When the Perl code in that job runs I would like it to be able to print the job ID (44 in this example).

Yes, I know that atq shows an = next to jobs that are executing, but there might be more than one of those at a time.

I could do something like pass a unique argument to the job when scheduling it, capture the ID, save that and the argument to a file somewhere, read that from the job.  That's a lot of work I'd rather not go to if I don't have to, and it seems like this should be simple but I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows is figured out by reading sources of at-3.14. The way at puts job id and the time when it is run into the file name should be similar for any version, but I haven't checked this.

To begin whith at encodes the job id and the time when a particular job should be run into the file name describing a job. The file name has format `aJJJJJTTTTTTTT`, where `JJJJJ` is 5 character hexadecimal string, the job id, and `TTTTTTTT` is an 8 character hexadecimal string, the time when the job should be run. The time is stored as seconds from the epoch.

At jobs are run by feeding a job description file as the standard input to `sh -c`. Fortunately the Linux kernel provides a symbolic link, `/proc/self/fd/0`, which will point to the standard input of the process currently being executed (play with `ls -l /proc/self/fd/0` in case you need to assure yourself that this indeed is so).

A file describing a job has been deleted by the time a job is run. However, the file is still available for the kernel because it has been duplicated with `dup(2)` before being used as the standard input for a job. So, actually we are resolving a symbolic link to a file name which is not visible any more. In the perl script at the end we need to take this into account as `readlink` will return something like `/foo/bar/baz (deleted)` instead of `/foo/bar/baz`. And we're interested in just the file name which has all the information we need.

The reason why the symbolic link points to a deleted file is because at daemon unlinks the original before executing the job. Unlinking gets done only after creating a copy, a hard link, which begins with `=` instead of `a`. With this the at daemon tries to ensure there will be only one copy of a job running: the daemon will not `execle(2)`, ie. it will bail out, should the `link(2)` fail. Because the original file has been subject to `open(2)` and `dup(2)` the inode is still there for the kernel to use because it still has hard links pointing to it.

After a fairly long and possibly confusing introduction, here is how to put it all together:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $job_file = readlink("/proc/self/fd/0");
if (index($job_file, " ") > 0) {
        $job_file = substr($job_file, 0, index($job_file, " ") - 1);
}
my $tmp = substr($job_file, rindex($job_file, "/") + 1);
$tmp =~ s/^a([0-9a-f]{5})[0-9a-f]+/$1/;
my $job_id = hex($tmp);

if ($job_id > 0) {
        printf("My AT job id is %d.\n", $job_id);
}

# end of file.
```

Comment: Wow.  Truly impressive.